# Cannot run tensorboard on AzureML, getting 502 error

Tags: azure, tensorflow, tensorboard, azure-machine-learning-service

I'm following the Microsoft documentation on how to run and view tensorboard from AzureML.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-monitor-tensorboard

I always get a 502 bad request error when hitting the URL that's output after running tb.start(), following each of the steps directly, or even just cloning the tutorial notebooks in the documentation above.

I've tried both Options (1 and 2) in the documentation above, and tried using different ports to 6006, such as 8088, all to no avail.

Has anyone got this working? Does anyone have any idea of what might be causing this issue?

Comment: You can refer to open GitHub issue: [Tensorboard not working following the documentation.](https://github.com/Azure/MachineLearningNotebooks/issues/1623)

Comment: Thanks, keeping an eye on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it does work if I run tensorboard from the terminal, not ideal but a decent workaround for the moment.